# Google sheets to get stock data on a specific date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am tying to get google sheets to produce stock quote on a given date. To do this I am using this code `=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "close", DATE(2023, 5, 20))` for example, but this is producing this error:

```
Error
When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'AAPL' returned no data.
```

Could you please advise how this error can be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GOOGLEFINANCE()` is pulling data from **https://www.google.com/finance**. If you check the data of `'AAPL'` in this link: **https://www.google.com/finance/quote/AAPL:NASDAQ**, you can see that there is no posted data for **MAY 20-21, 2023**.
[image]

I have tried your formula and it is now displaying data without error but it is showing the latest data available as of the moment. (May 22, 2023)
[image]

**Data from 5-15-2023 to 5-23-2023**
[image]